# Wix removing unloaded files

Tags: wix, windows-installer

We have a office addin which is installed with a msi created in wix. the msi is deployed with a companywide installation tool silently at a point when people may have office open.

The problem we have is that not all the dlls we have will be loaded when the addin runs but will run as required on first use. if the installer runs it will replace the unloaded dlls in the background and if the application tries to load them at a later time the file/s will not be present and therefore cause a crash.

Steps:

1. addin version 1 loads which is compiled with version 1 of dll
2. user is using addin but dll version 1 is not loaded
3. An automated installation begins that replaces dll version 1 with version 2
4. user is still using version 1 of the addin but they now use the functionality that requires the dll.
5. The addin tries to load dll version 1 but the file is not found and the addin crashes
6. The user restarts which loads version2 of the addin and version 2 of dll and all is fine

Is there a way in wix to say not to replace a dll if all files cannot be replaced? or is a there a known way round this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This scenario is called "torn state". It usually happens because a restart request was ignored.

In this case, typically addin v2 dll wouldn't replace addin v1 dll because v1 was in use and a restart would be required. Since the unused support dlls we're successfully replaced the system is unstable until the restart is taken.

Detecting this situation can be bypassed if addin dlls are shadow copied which allows all of the files to be replaced without requiring a restart.

There isn't a great solution to torn state other than to proactively get the addin released (by requiring any host processes to stop) and blocking the install or forcing a restart if that isn't possible. `CloseApp` and `RestartResource` elements can help here.

The alternatives (which MSI does not support) are to use transacted file system operations. Unfortunately, that does not work out on reality (it was attempted in Windows Longhorn/Vista and was a disaster). Or implement "hot patching" where the loaded v1 addin's code is updated to v2 in memory. But I don't think MSI supports that either (and it is technically very challenging to use).

Comment: For anyone else with same issue. What we ended up doing was to put the version 2 dlls in a subfolder and added a codeBase entry to the app config file to point to the new folder while still leaving the original version 1 dll in the original location. This allowed clients already running to use the existing dll and when the addin reloads it will use the dlls in the subfolder. Not the greatest solution but the best we could come up with